# How to manage menuStrip in Mdiparent from child form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms : Login (child) and Form1 (as MdiParent).
The login form has 3 roles and each role has different access control to the menuStrip

**Example:** menuStrip in form1:

```
-file (login, logout)
master (register, view)
```

role : admin, trainer, trainee.
after login, menu which can be accessed for admin is file (login, logout) and master(view) only.

So my question is how to disable/hide the menu register for admin in login form?

Comment: WinForms or WebForms or something else? Please describe the problem in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Once the admin logs in successfully, you can simply go to the specific menu item you want to hide by it's name and set it's `Visible` property to `false`:

```
((Form1)this.MdiParent).RegisterMenuItem.Visible = false;
```

You will have to make sure that the menu item is not private. It must be internal or public.

Comment: I have tried it. The register menu item (which i need to disable from admin access) can not be accessed or managed (its visibility) from child form.

Comment: how to know whether the menu item is public or not? bcs ive tried your codes before, it wasnt error but still admin can access the register menu and its visible for admin (while on this case, i need to disable admin access for the register menu)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create a public method in MDI form that contains the logic to disable the register menu and then you call it from the Login form like this:

In the MDI Form:

```
public void DisableRegisterMenu()
{
    registerMenuItem.Enabled = false;
}
```

In the Login form:

```
var parent = (Form1) MdiParent;
parent.DisableRegisterMenu();
```

/A

Comment: ive tried that too but after login as admin, the register menu is still visible and can be accessed by admin.

Comment: Have you checked so that you don't have any code the reset this menu item in the parent that interfers ?

Comment: Sorry i dont understand what you mean. Ive done that but still the codes didnt work.

Comment: I Think you need to add some more code to this question so I can see how you are trying to solve it.

Comment: By the looks of it your code should work, have you tried to add a Watch to the regToolStripMenuItem.Visible property to see if the property is set to true somewhere else in the code ?

Comment: i dont know but i think i havent tried it, could you please post the example of the codes you mean?

Comment: What you is when you are running in debug, mark that property and select add Watch, then you will be able to see if the Visible property Changes from false to true somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
this is my login form codes :

                        if (count == 1)
                        {

                            UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUser = (string)rdr["UserName"];
                            MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + comboBox1.Text + UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUser);

                            UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUser = (string)rdr["UserRole"];
                            if (UserInformation.CurrentLoggedInUser == "Administrator")
                            {
                                this.Close();
                                this.MdiParent = new Form1();
                               // ((Form1)this.MdiParent).hide();
                                //((Register_Training_Participant)this.MdiParent).Hide();
                                var parent = (Form1)MdiParent;
                                parent.AdminDisableControl();


                            }

//this is the code for my mainform :
public void AdminDisableControl()
        {
            regToolStripMenuItem.Visible = false;

        }
```